# Fixed Header and Footer design When Scroll on Content Browser Footer is Jumping

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]
Hi,

Its My Fixed Header and Footer When i am scrolling Browser. Browser Header is Hidden that time my Footer is jumping How Can i Fix it.. I have attached jumping ScreenShot Below :

[image]..

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff transition: top .5s ease;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px z-index: 999;
}

#main {
  padding-top: 50px;
  transition: padding-top .2s ease;
}

.fullContainer {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header id="header"></header>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
  <main id="main">
    <div class="fullContainer">
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: can u attach your code?

Comment: I attached my code 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this css for your header and footer.

```
.fixed-header{
  position: fixed;   
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed-footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

While scrolling the page, if your content overlaps on the header and footer means please add a z-index for both header and footer as required

Comment: Its Not Working Mobile Devices when i scroll that browser Url Header Hidden that time Only i got Footer Jumping Problem

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#root {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#root > * {
  width: 100%;
}
#header, #footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#main {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header id="header">fixed header</header>
  <main id="main">
    <div class="fullContainer">
      your content here
      ...
      <hr>
      let's test with something tall
      ....
      <div style="height: 400vh"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer">fixed footer</footer>
</div>
```

It also works with short content:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#root {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#header, #footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#main {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header id="header">fixed header</header>
  <main id="main">
    <div class="fullContainer">
      your content here
      ...
      <hr>
      let's test with something small
      ....
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer">fixed footer</footer>
</div>
```

Cross browser, cross device, no jumping guaranteed, as it doesn't rely on positioning.

---

The only problem it might have, on some designs, is that the `#header`, `#main` and `#footer` don't actually overlap and this can be a problem if you want the header (and/or footer) to be displayed over the background (or contents) of `#main`.

To tackle this ***rare** edge case*, you have at least a couple of solutions:

- ***a)*** don't place the background on `#main`, place it on `#root` or even `body`. problem solved.
- ***b)*** if, for some design reason (let's say header and footer are semi-transparent and they make stuff under them blurry - which is a cool effect) you actually want the content of `#main` to scroll under them, so it gets blurred as you scroll, you *will* have to use JavaScript.
  You want to give `#main` a top negative margin (and a matching positive top padding) equal to `#header`'s height and a bottom negative margin (matched with a positive bottom padding) equal to the `#footer`'s height. And, obviously, give both `#header` and `#footer` a higher `z-index` value than `#main`'s.
  The JS would be used to update the margins/paddings when header/footer change height.

I started writing on how to tackle this (again there are a couple of options) but at some point I realized the answer is getting too long, all because of trying to solve an edge case. If you have this particular edge case, ask it as another question and I'll answer there.